# Почему не точно выполняется условие?

Tags: php

Обычный код для заполнения строки он должен заполнять строку 7 символами (рандомными) но иногда бывает такое что выдает и 3 и 2 символа в место 7 в чем причина ?

```
<?php
$byk = "qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM1234567890{}[].,:;?";
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    $rand = rand(1,73);
    $ban=$byk[$rand];
        $itog.=$ban;
}
echo $itog;
```

Comment: не стоит так делать, если вопрос решен то его лучше оставить, потому что он может помочь кому то в будущем

Comment: Пожалуйста, не создавайте лишнюю работу другим участникам, вандализируя собственные посты. При размещении сообщения на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском» вы даёте SO, в соответствии с лицензией [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.ru), неотзываемое право на распространение своего контента. В соответствии с политикой SO любые вандальные действия будут отменены. Если вы желаете узнать больше про удаление постов, пожалуйста, прочитайте ["Как работает удаление?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/223536).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что длина строки в переменной `$byk` меньше на две единицы, чем максимально генерируемое число в `rand(1,73)`, и если рандомно выпадает несуществующий индекс *(72 или 73)*, то в результирующую переменную не добавляется ничего. Что бы избежать этого, нужно делать замер длины строки, и это значение брать за максимум для рандомного генератора:

```
$str = "qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM1234567890{}[].,:;?";

$max = strlen($str) - 1;
$result = '';

for ($i = 0; ++$i <= 7;) {
    $rand = rand(0, $max);
    $result .= $str[$rand];
}

echo $result;
```